# What's wrong with image rotation code?

Tags: java, algorithm, graphics, rotation

The image rotates with code below, but wrong, some black dots appears on original image. I believe it's something with rotation code. Any solution? Thanks. The image dimensions is 32x32 pixels loaded on center of screen (320x240).

```
public class RendPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int widthe  = 320;
    int heighte = 240;

    double angle = Math.toRadians(220);
    double sin = Math.sin(angle);
    double cos = Math.cos(angle);
    double x0 = 0.5 * (widthe  - 1);     // point to rotate about
    double y0 = 0.5 * (heighte - 1);     // center of image

    public static BufferedImage fbuffer;
    public RendPanel(int width, int height) {
        fbuffer = new BufferedImage(320, 240, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        BufferedImage in = null;
        try { in = ImageIO.read(new File("square.png")); } //32x32 square .png
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        for (int i = 0; i < in.getWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < in.getHeight(); j++) {
                fbuffer.setRGB(i + (320 / 2) - 16, j + (240 / 2) - 16, in.getRGB(i, j));
            }
        }

        BufferedImage neww = new BufferedImage(320, 240, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        for (int x = 0; x < widthe; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < heighte; y++) {
                if(x >= x0 - 32 && x <= x0 + 32 && y >= y0 - 32 && y <= y0 + 32){
                    double a = x - x0;
                    double b = y - y0;
                    int xx = (int) (+a * cos - b * sin + x0);
                    int yy = (int) (+a * sin + b * cos + y0);

                    // plot pixel (x, y) the same color as (xx, yy) if it's in bounds
                    if (xx >= 0 && xx < width && yy >= 0 && yy < height) {
                        neww.setRGB(xx, yy, fbuffer.getRGB(x, y));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        fbuffer = neww;
        repaint();

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(fbuffer, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Man, it's strange, because in this code it works properly!

Heres a working code:

```
public class RendPanel extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    int widthe  = 320;
    int heighte = 240;

    int ang = 0;
    double x0 = 0.5 * (widthe  - 1);     // point to rotate about
    double y0 = 0.5 * (heighte - 1);     // center of image

    public static BufferedImage fbuffer;
    public RendPanel(int width, int height) {
        fbuffer = new BufferedImage(320, 240, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        BufferedImage in = null;
        try { in = ImageIO.read(new File("square.png")); } //32x32 square .png
        catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        for (int i = 0; i < in.getWidth(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < in.getHeight(); j++) {
                fbuffer.setRGB(i + (320 / 2) - 16, j + (240 / 2) - 16, in.getRGB(i, j));
            }
        }

        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    }

    BufferedImage neww;
    public void r(){
        neww = new BufferedImage(320, 240, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

        double angle = Math.toRadians(ang);
        double sin = Math.sin(angle);
        double cos = Math.cos(angle);

        for (int x = 0; x < widthe; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < heighte; y++) {
                if(x >= x0 - 32 && x <= x0 + 32 && y >= y0 - 32 && y <= y0 + 32){
                    double a = x - x0;
                    double b = y - y0;
                    int xx = (int) (+a * cos - b * sin + x0);
                    int yy = (int) (+a * sin + b * cos + y0);

                    // plot pixel (x, y) the same color as (xx, yy) if it's in bounds
                    if (xx >= 0 && xx < widthe && yy >= 0 && yy < heighte) {
                        neww.setRGB(x, y, fbuffer.getRGB(xx, yy));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        ang++;
        repaint();
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(neww, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

Thanks for:
https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/Rotation.java.html

EDIT:
You have to invert the vars on `bf2.setRGB(x, y, fbuffer.getRGB(xx, yy));` to the rotated coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

A beginner's mistake (sorry).

Taking every source pixel in turn, transforming the coordinates to the destination and copying the pixel value is not the right way.because the regular input grid will not map to a regular grid, and there will be voids (and overlaps).

The correct way is to scan the destination image (so that every destination pixel is reached) and counter-transform the coordinates to fetch the pixel value from the source.

As a refinement, you can use the four neighboring pixel from where you land in the source and perform bilinear interpolation, to reduce aliasing.

Comment: Is wrong rotate a rotated result? I was trying rotated the rotated values, and now I can see that I should vary the angle but use a normal image to rotated for every angle, right? Is this required (mathematically)?

Comment: @JonathanCosta: what ??

Comment: After perform a rotation, if we want perform again but using other angles, we need use original image to generate from next angle, right?

Comment: @JonathanCosta: not cecessarily, but this is more accurate.